# ElasticSearch ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation when I'm using Logback

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j, log4j2, logback

I am using logback for logging in my application

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And in my class i use this

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ElasticSearchRepository.class.getName());
```

In dependency analyzer, I found that elasticsearch uses log4j-api 2.11.1

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>6.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have this error:

> ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation.
>   Please add log4j-core to the classpath.
>   Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...

I resolved it by excluding log4j-api from elasticsearch dependency, but on the other hand, I have got this error:

> Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger

I have got the Log4j dependency back by removing the exclusion but I had the first error also back, and I have no intention of adding log4j jars since I am already using logback

Answer (score 0):

Adding this dependency seems to resolve it.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This did not generate conflicts with logback which is good enough, the only sad thing is that I added a dependency to just resolve an error and not for feature purposes.

Comment: Where did you add this? What is that file? Where it is?