# ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. But i am not using any logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j

When I run my project I get this error :

> ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation.
> Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to
> the console...

The thing is I am not using Log4j anywhere in my project. I don't have it in my pom.xml, I don't use it or import it in any of my class, so why do I have this error message?

Here is a screen of what i get when i search for "log" in my whole project :

[image]

As you can see, no use of any logger.

I don't know what other information I can provide so feel free to ask.

EDIT : I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881821/error-statuslogger-log4j2-could-not-find-a-logging-implementation)

Comment: Try looking for the log4j2 references into your IDE's settings. Or try [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209205/elasticsearch-error-statuslogger-log4j2-could-not-find-a-logging-implementation?rq=1)

Comment: How can i look for the log4j2 references? Im on intelliJ

Comment: Try in Run configuration if there's something about log4j2/JUnit setted